# Расположение div c фиксированной и процентной шириной в обертке

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Проблему описал в картинке. При попытке реализовать данный макет постоянно что то куда то съезжает либо остается без изменений. 
div с шириной 1000px, в нем два div ширина которых в сумме 400px. Свободно остается 600px, если я третьему блоку указываю 100%, он забирает 100% от родителя. Использовал calc(100% - 400px) всеравно третий блок съезжает вниз. margin and padding 0px;

**ВАЖНО! Хотелось бы решение, которое будет работать во всех популярных браузерах.**

Так же прошу поделится информацией, где можно почитать\посмотреть про верстку, а именно позиционирование элементов. Я много читал\смотрел. Все понятно все работает, но пытаюсь реализовать свою задумку и все начинает вести себя по другому. 
[image: Задача]

Используя "display: flex" получаю следующее: ширина 174px, хотя в css указал 250px; как так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: посмотрите здесь http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/tipovye-makety/rezinovyi-trekhkolonochnyi-maket

Comment: А вы учли `border` и `padding`?

Comment: margin и padding 0px; border я не указывал и думаю что он по умолчанию 0px;

Comment: Учите математику: *200px* + *250px* = *450px*, а не *400px*

Comment: Я тут указал 200 и 250. Я уже путаться начинаю, у себя я указал 200 и 200 calc(100% - 400px) не работает, а calc(100% - 420px) работает но остается 5-10 px незанятого места

Comment: Чтобы 100% + border + padding = 100% - посмотрите здесь http://htmlbook.ru/css/box-sizing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример с использованием `display: table;`

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.b{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.b-item{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    padding: 15px;
}
.b-item:nth-of-type(1),
.b-item:nth-of-type(3){
    width: 200px;
}
.b-item:nth-of-type(2){
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="b">
    <div class="b-item">
        200px
    </div>
    <div class="b-item">
        100% - 400px
    </div>
    <div class="b-item">
        200px
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я бы старался избегать любых таблиц для разметки (даже в css в виде display: table) в 2017 году-то

Comment: @andreymal все зависит требований заказчика.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по тому, что в скриншоте вы использовали флексбокс, вам надо поработать со свойствами `flex-grow` и `flex-shrink`.

`flex-grow` необходимо поставить блоку, который будет увеличиваться; это свойство отвечает за пропорциональное увеличение блоков.

`flex-shrink` необходимо поставить блокам с фиксированной шириной, чтобы избежать их уменьшения; это свойство отвечает за пропорционально уменьшение блоков.

Также для простоты рекомендую использовать блочную модель `box-sizing: border-box` — таким образом ширина, которую вы указываете, будет включать в себя внутренние отступы и границы.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.block {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.block--1 {
  width: 150px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background: #ff8383;
}

.block--2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background: #82e082;
}

.block--3 {
  width: 100px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background: #9999e6;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block block--1">150px</div>
  <div class="block block--2">100%</div>
  <div class="block block--3">100px</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно что у вас происходит. Вообще надо показывать ваш код. Если вам надо современные решения - используйте `flexbox`.  На `CSS-tricks` хорошо расписано - [тыц](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 1000px;
  display: flex;
}
div {
  border: 2px solid;
  height: 100px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.one {
  width: 200px;
}
.two {
  width: 100%;
}
.three {
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="three"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

При добавлении `calc` нужно учитывать границы `border` соседних элементов, их `padding` и `margin`

```css
.main {display: inline-block; width:1000px; border:3px solid black;height: 100px;}
.left {
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 200px; 
  height: 100px;
  border-right: 3px solid black;
}
.right {
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 250px; 
  height: 100px; 
  border-left: 3px solid black;
}
.center {
  display: inline-block; 
  width: calc(100% - 450px - 6px);
  height: 100px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="main"><div class="left"></div><div class="center"></div><div class="right"></div></div>
```